# Some of parameters are being inserted in firebase real-time database Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to insert 4 spinners (animal,gender,sterilization and age), 2 editText (Name and breed), one generated id (pet id )and the user id in firebase database. But, only 2 spinners (gender and sterilization), petId and user id are being inserted in the real time database firebase. Below are the java file and the database part. I wanted to insert the values of all 4 spinners, 2 editText fields, the generated petId and the userId in the real-time database.

[image: 1st Part]

public void addListenerOnButton() {

```
    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

            String animal = String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());

            Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

           String gender;
            gender=String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());

            Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

            String sterilization;
            sterilization=String.valueOf(spinner3.getSelectedItem());

            Spinner spinnerAge = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerAge);

            String age;
            age=String.valueOf(spinnerAge.getSelectedItem());

                EditText edtName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);

                EditText edtbreed= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Breed);

                String name=edtName.getText().toString().trim();
                String breed=edtbreed.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    edtName.setError("Email is required");
                    edtName.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(breed)) {
                    edtbreed.setError("Password is required");
                    edtbreed.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }

                String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                String id = Pets.push().getKey();

                Pet pet1 = new Pet(id,age,breed,animal,gender,name,sterilization,currentuser);

                Pets.child(id).setValue(pet1);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pet Added"  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    });
}
```

}

[image: Database Part]

This is the part where only 4 out of 8 values are being inserted database.

[image: Pet class 1st Part]

[image: Pet Class 2nd Part]

Comment: Add ur pet1 POJO class

Comment: next time post the actual code not screenshots please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.Age = Age` instead of `Age = Age`. Since the name of the parameter and the name of the Class member is the same. Which causes you 'Shadowing' of the names and assigns Parameter `Age`'s value to it self and not the class member.

The same situation applies to `Name`, `Breed` & `Category`. So, only the other fields are assigned a value, hence they are added to firebase DB.

**Note:**
You should use [java naming conventions](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions). Instead of 'Age' it should be 'age'.